# How to use Symfony DI Service Container properly?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am refactoring some soap service where static methods is used for logging and calling db instance. It is a custom made code, not framework. Db is singleton so it has object calling:

```
Db->getInstance()->prepare("some pepared statement");
```

and Logger is normal static method:

```
Logger::log("Some log massage!");
```

I want to change all that and i implemented Symfony service container and registered those two services:

```
    $container->register('Logger', 'Helpers\LogHelpers\LogManager');
    $container->register('Db', 'Helpers\ConfigHelpers\Db');
```

Now should i inject those services to all classes in the project or is there a way to use those services from some global variable? I can call services from container statically but what's the point then of making container, right? I am asking this because it seems much complicated to inject them everywhere. Another way is to register all classes as services with Logger and Db dependencies like this:

```
        $container->register('SKSPartner', 'Partners\SKSPartner')->setArguments([
        new Reference('SKSSoapClient'),
        new Reference('Db'),
        new Reference('Logger'),
        new Reference('ServerManager')
    ]);
    $container->register('ThirdPartyIntegrationPartner', 'Partners\ThirdPartyIntegrationPartner')->setArguments([
        new Reference('ThirdPartyIntegrationSoapClient'),
        new Reference('Db'),
        new Reference('Logger'),
        new Reference('ServerManager')
    ]);
```

and then to use those big classes as services. But then all part of project will became services. As i understand in service container there should be registered only classes/services that will be used again and again as Logger and Db? Some help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Your understanding that only reusable services should be defined is not correct.  Ideally, all the users of services would also be services.  There are alternative approaches as the accepted answer suggests but make sure you use them for the correct reasons.

Comment: @Cerad I tried now the approach with only reusable services(Db and Logger) and, to be honest, something doesn't feel right. I had to inject services on too many places. I will try now to make everything a service and Db and Logger will be dependencies that will be defined in container itself(like in my second example above). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having them injected everywhere is by-the-book, however, I understand the hassle of having to go everywhere and do so. Have you tried investigating [Symfony service Autowiring?](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) That one *could* come very handy in this case.

Another approach, that you mentioned, of having some global variable from which you could pull your services on demand is basically your container, but global. But the thing is that, In DI pattern, injecting (and much less using global) container is highly discouraged. Injecting container because is discouraged because of dependency reference cycle being create very easily, and global container because inability to write mock tests properly.

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: So basically i should try to use auto wiring or to inject Logger and Db to all classes. The approach to register all classes as services with Db, Logger and all other dependencies is wrong. Also, the only way to make container global is with some static method in which container should be but it is wrong also and there is no change then from using static methods to fetch Logger and Db like in the first version of the project. I will try to implement auto wiring first to see how it works. Thanks, i got something to work with now!